# Always visible notifications in gnome3

Tags: gnome, notification-area

I've installed **Gnome3** on Ubuntu 11.04 via the ppa and it mostly works fine. However I am a bit unhappy about the notification panel being invisible. I understand the general concept of notifications being shown for a short amount of time and then you can find them again in the unobstrusive notification tray. However this neglects the use case that I did not notice the on-screen notification (e.g. talking on the phone, or having left the computer for a second or two).

So if I miss a notification I will have to check the tray to see it. Basically this means that I am checking the tray all the time for missing notifications which is really counter-productive.

Is there some way to get the notification tray to stay visible? Or to have it in the top-panel? Or any other means to see "notifications pending"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the present moment, there is a temporary solution which comes in the form of a **gnome-shell-extension**. You can read more about the extension [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/move-icons-from-message-tray-to-top.html). However, this issue of missing notification is something that is being worked on for the upcoming gnome 3.2 update which will be released in September 28th 2011.

Comment: I am now running gnome-shell 3.2.2 on Fedora 16 and it still hasn't fixed the problem. Any new information on that?